# Definition of power set uses strict subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the following [lecture notes](https://people.bath.ac.uk/masmdp/measdir.bho/notesp1to27.pdf) one finds the following:

> Examples. The following are all examples of σ-algebras. (HW: check
> this in each case) • Let P(X) denote the collection of all subsets of
> X, i.e. P(X) := {A : A ⊂ X} (we write ⊂ rather than ⊆, so in our
> notation X ⊂ X is a true statement). P(X) is called the power set of
> X, and is a σ-algebra.

I don't understand how using the strict subset makes X ⊂ X a true statement, or what the author is trying to get across here?

Comment: The parenthetical remark is telling you that he uses $\subset$ to mean non-strict subset. Many people do. When they want to indicate a strict subset, they write $\subsetneq$ or $\subsetneqq$. The sad fact is that $\subset$ is ambiguous: many people use it for strict subset, and many others use it for non-strict subset. For that reason I prefer not to use it at all: I use $\subseteq$ for non-strict subset and $\subsetneqq$ for strict subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the author says:

> "we write $\subset$ rather than $\subseteq$, so in our notation $X\subset X$ is a true statement."

They are using the symbol "$\subset$" as a synonym for "$\subseteq$." (This leaves the symbol "$\subsetneq$" for *proper* subsethood.) [Munrkes' topology textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DVPYWG8) also follows this convention.

Personally I think this is a terrible choice since it clashes with "$<$ vs. $\le$," but they are being consistent and stating it explicitly.